# How to override a value of a single field in an object without copying the entire objects values

Tags: java, spring

I want to replace a certain field deep inside an object of objects.

The value I need to replace is in the Voucher object and it is located from

CarBookingRequest>CarSegment>RentalPayentPref>Voucher>type

At the moment, this is my code

```
//generate new voucher type for SV
            String currencyCode = originalRequest.getCarSegment().getCarTotalPrice().getCurrencyCode();
            String amount = originalRequest.getCarSegment().getCarTotalPrice().getAmount();
            String carTotalPrice = currencyCode + amount;

            //get Old Voucher values and re-assign type to carTotalPrice
            Voucher voucher = new Voucher();
            voucher.setBillingNumber(originalRequest.getCarSegment().getRentalPaymentPref().getVoucher().getBillingNumber());
            voucher.setFormat(originalRequest.getCarSegment().getRentalPaymentPref().getVoucher().getFormat());
            voucher.setType(carTotalPrice);

            RentalPaymentPref rentalPaymentPref = new RentalPaymentPref();
            rentalPaymentPref.setVoucher(voucher);

            CarSegment carSegment = new CarSegment();
            carSegment.setRentalPaymentPref(rentalPaymentPref);

            originalRequest.setCarSegment(carSegment);
```

How do I do it without removing the existing values from all of this other objects as afterall, this objects above the voucher has their own values that I dont need to change but needs to be retained. As this values are already assigned to variable that is being referenced on another code. This class is being referenced close to this below in the code.

```
CarBookingRequest newRequesst = originalRequestBody;
```

I tried manually instantiating all of the high level classes and just overwriting the values I need, but it also removes the existing values from other params that doesnt need changing.

Here is my sample model class:

CarbookingRequest.class

```
 public class CarBookingRequest {
           
        private CarSegment carSegment;
        private List<Remark> remarks;
        private String test;
    
    }
```

CarSegment.class

```
public class CarSegment {
       
    private String billingNumber;
    private RentalPayentPref rental;
    private String test;

}
```

RentalPayentPref.class

```
public class RentalPayentPref {
       
    private Voucher Voucher;
    private String test;

}
```

Voucher.class

```
public class Voucher {
       
    private String amount;
    private String type;

}
```

Comment: Show the code where you are trying to update the value. So that it is bit clearer what you are trying and how you are trying it.

Comment: just added my code. to add, this model classes has alot of fields in it, hence manually copying all of it will take alot of time and make the code long, hence I am looking for a way to change the value of a single field in this object inside of several objects with varying values in its different fields.

Comment: If classes have setter, then just use it, or try to build new object using existing object  (like builder pattern).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why are you creating new objects, when you can get the existing objects from getter methods. You provided getter methods only in your answer, and not in the question. You can use them as follows:

```
originalRequest
  .getCarSegment()
  .getRentalPaymentPref()
  .getVoucher()
  .setType(newValue);
```

Comment: Owh, okay. I was initially doing this as originalRequest.setCarSegment().setRentalPaymentPref()...... but is requiring me to set the values and modify the existing model classes with constructors or new functions etc....... didn't knew this is what I am supposed to do to set it. Thanks. This seems a better and shorter implementation than the one I had answered below. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Just realized I could do this with this single line of code.

```
Optional.ofNullable(originalRequest)
                    .map(CarBookingRequest::getCarSegment)
                    .map(CarSegment::getRentalPaymentPref)
                    .map(RentalPaymentPref::getVoucher)
                    .ifPresent(voucher -> voucher.setType(carTotalPrice));
```

My Issue is resolved now. Though the other answer I marked as answer above would prolly be the better and shorter version of this as there is no need for maps already and the existing values is still retained.